# How to free and nil an unknown object instance by reference/pointer?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a container which hold a single control. this control can be one of few types (`TMyFrame` descendants). the controls are being created and destroyed at run time.

At some point I need to Free **and** nil this control:

```
var
  C: TControl;

  C := SomeForm.MyContainer.Controls[0];
  C.Free;
  C := nil;
```

But the problem is that the control instance itself is not set to nil.

Is this possible?

---

I guess the key point is that an instance could have many references to it. I just realized that one reference cannot "see" all other unknown references.

Comment: Does SomeForm.MyContainer.Controls[0] return a pointer or a copy?

If it returns a copy then you are free and nilling the copy -> C will be nil.

 
If it is a pointer then the SomeForm.MyContainer.Controls[0] should be nil

So try to figure out what gets returned....

Comment: @Blaatz0r `Controls[]` is an indexed property of `TWinControl` that returns a `TControl`, which is, of course, a reference.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan didn't notice the SomeForm before the .MyContainer :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, The control reference is found in `TSomeForm` (`FActiveControl`) - but suppose I can't access this reference directly. Mybe the question should have been "How to free and nil an unknown object reference by reference/pointer"?

Comment: @Zig You know how to free the control. If you don't explicitly keep a reference to the control when you create it, there is nothing to `nil`. That would be the final paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "The control reference is found in TSomeForm (FActiveControl) " - there **is** a reference to that control. but I wondering if I can nil it, by a pointer to that reference (`C: TControl`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

According to your comment, you are not storing a reference to the control when you create it dynamically. In which case there is no need for you to set anything to `nil`.

The VCL framework itself holds various references to controls. But these are managed by the framework. You mention 
`ActiveControl`. If you destroy the active control then the framework takes care of managing the `ActiveControl` property.

There is simply nothing you need to do beyond destroying the control. **You** don't need to clear a reference because **you** did not take a reference.

---

There is a mechanism for automatically setting references to `nil`. It is implemented in `TComponent`. In the destructor of `TComponent` there is a call to `SetReference(False)` is made and that is implemented like this:

```
procedure TComponent.SetReference(Enable: Boolean);
var
  Field: ^TComponent;
begin
  if (FOwner <> nil) then
  begin
    Field := FOwner.FieldAddress(FName);
    if Field <> nil then
      if Enable then Field^ := Self else Field^ := nil;
  end;
end;
```

So, suppose that you have a form like this:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;
```

where the two buttons are created by the form streaming framework. Suppose that in `Button2Click` you write `Button1.Free`. Then the call to `SetReference` will set the `Button1` variable to `nil`.

Now, you are talking about a control created at runtime. You did not show us how you defined the reference that is not being set to `nil`. If you want to arrange that the reference is automatically set to `nil` you need to do the following:

1. Declare the reference as a published field of the control's `Owner`.
2. Ensure that the control's `Name` is the same as the published field you declared in step 1.

If you cannot do that, then you will need to manually write code to set the reference to `nil`. Do that like this:

```
SomeReference := nil;
```

Now, I don't know how you are going to get hold of `SomeReference`. Only you can know that. Because only you know the location of this reference that you wish to set to `nil`.

Or perhaps the whole question is a complete misunderstanding. Perhaps you do not have a reference to the dynamically created control. In which case, use `Controls[]` or some other means to locate the control, call `Free`, and the job is done.

Comment: I guess the key point is that an instance could have many references to it. I just realized that one reference cannot "see" all other unknown references.

Comment: And I meant `FActiveControl` or `FMyActiveControl` (not *the* `ActiveControl` property) which *has* the reference to that instance.

Comment: OK. As it happens, the property is a straight read of the field: `property ActiveControl: TWinControl read FActiveControl`

Comment: My question referred to a situation where I **cant** access `FActiveControl` or `property ActiveControl`.  and had only a local reference as `C := SomeForm.MyContainer.Controls[0]`

Comment: The basic rule is that if you have a reference that outlives the object then you should consider clearing that reference. In your scenario you don't have a reference that outlives the object.

Answer (score 2):

An object instance cannot be nilled, and in this case there is no need for any reference to set to `nil`.

If `Container.Controls[0]` is valid, then `Container` is the control's parent. When you free that control, the VCL takes care of extracting a gone child from a parent, so after you free `Container.Controls[0]`, `ControlCount` will be `0` and `Container.Controls[0]` will be invalid.

Comment: plus one for "An object instance cannot be nilled".